# Azure Premium File Share slow over SMB

Tags: windows, azure, windows-10, server-message-block, azure-storage

I m trying to use Azure Premium Azure file share as a mounted drive with SMB 3.0 on windows 10.

But the performance are not that great, the upload is around 55mb/s

and the download is around 20mb/s for files that are around 60mb, and around 50mb/s for larger files around 2gb

the file share is configured for 3072 Gib so Egress rate should be around 240Mb/s and Ingress rate should be around 160Mb/s

The connection to the computer is via optical fiber and reaches 900mb/s download and 500mb/s upload so this should not be the bottle neck.

SMB 3.0 is probably not using the full potential of the connection and not paralyzing enough to get more output.

Any idea on how I can achieve better output with Azure Premium File Share mounted on windows 10?

Edit:
I did some more test and comparison:
downloading 37 files for a total of 2060004987 bytes
takes 0.3334 minutes with AZCOPY
takes 1.06   minutes with SMB

So SMB is 3 times slower than AZCOPY can I improve that?

Comment: Can you test upload speeds using Az Copy? This will eliminate the SMB part and do it over the rest API. You could also do the same copy to blob storage to see if there is a difference.

Comment: @SamCogan I have added AZCOPY as reference, and it's 3 times faster! any idea?